# LinkedList Java traverse and print

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I would really appreciate if you can help to answer to this question:

I have already created a custom linked list myself in a very standard way using Java. Below are my classes:

```
public class Node {

   private Object obj;
   private Node next;

   public Node(Object obj){
       this(obj,null);
   }

   public Node(Object obj,Node n){
       this.obj = obj;
       next = n;
   }

   public void setData(Object obj){
       this.obj = obj;
   }

   public void setNext(Node n){
       next = n;
   }

   public Object getData(){
       return obj;
   }

   public Node getNext(){
       return next;
   }

}




public class linkedList {
    private Node head;


    public linkedList(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void setHead(Node n){
        head = n;
    }

    public Node getHead(){
        return head;
    }


   public void add(Object obj){
       if(getHead() == null){
           Node tmp = new Node(obj);
           tmp.setNext(getHead());
           setHead(tmp);
       }else{
           add(getHead(),obj);
       }
   }


   private void add(Node cur,Object obj){
       if(cur.getNext() == null){
           Node tmp = new Node(obj);
           tmp.setNext(cur.getNext());
           cur.setNext(tmp);
       }else{
           add(cur.getNext(),obj);
       }
   }


}
```

Im trying to print value i have inserted into the list as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Node l = new Node("ant");
        Node rat = new Node("rat");
        Node bat = new Node("bat");
        Node hrs = new Node("hrs");

        linkedList lst = new linkedList();
        lst.add(l);
        lst.add(rat);
        lst.add(bat);
        lst.add(hrs);



        Node tmp = lst.getHead();
        while(tmp != null){

            System.out.println(tmp.getData());
            tmp = tmp.getNext();

        }


    }
```

but the output i got from the IDE is

```
linklist.Node@137bd6a1
linklist.Node@2747ee05
linklist.Node@635b9e68
linklist.Node@13fcf0ce
```

why does it print out the reference but not the actual value of the string such as bat,ant,rat... ?

If i want to print out the actual value then what should i do?

Thank you very much

Comment: This is an aside, but why aren't you using generics?

Comment: you can add toString() method to your Node class, then it should print fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `linkedList` class already creates the `Node`s for you!

```
linkedList list = new linkedList();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
Node tmp = lst.getHead();
while(tmp != null){
    System.out.println(tmp.getData());
    tmp = tmp.getNext();
}
```

Will print

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `toString()` method on `Node`:

```
@Override
String toString() {
  String val = // however you want to represent your Node
  return val;
}
```

and print the node:

```
System.out.println(tmp);
```

Alternatively, have `Node.getData()` return a `String` if you know you are only going to store `String`s -- change the `Object`s to `String` in the `Node` definition

Alternatively, you could use generics to specify the type of data inside the node

UPDATE: after a little more thought (provoked by comments), I see something amiss:

`tmp.getData()` should return a string (based on Node's single parameter ctor and that you are passing strings), but the output is about references to `Node` objects.  Is it possible that `linkedList.add` re-sets the `Node`'s obj member to a `Node` instead?

Comment: @Jeffrey - there must be something wrong somewhere -- might be me :)  The OP said that `System.out.println(tmp.getData());` prints references, but that should return a string (the stored object), however, the actual output shows `Node`s being printed...

Answer (score -1):

The LinkedList is of Objects, Objects toString method prints out the reference. If you want to print out the string you are going to have either change the LinkedList to a String/Generics or cast the print out like this:

```
String output = (String)tmp.getData();
System.out.println(output);
```

(you can do this in one line if you want).

Comment: `linkedList` is his own class.

Comment: @Jeffrey `LinkedList` is tmp is of the type `Node` which is his class as well The Node's Data (returned by `getData()`) is of Type `Object`.

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` does not have a `getHead` method. Also, `System.out.println((Object) "hello")` will print `hello`, not the reference to the object. Method overriding takes care of that.

Comment: @Jeffrey He's not using `java.util.LinkedList` he wrote his own. The code is in the Question.

Comment: @Jeffrey .. Yeah you are right i add node object into the list that's one of the mistakes    @ twain249 i did change everything to string and it works .. Thank you all anyway

Comment: if you call .toString() on a Object which is String it will call the same toString() method after casting it to String.

Answer (score -1):

Your getData() in Node class returns an Object type. You need to cast it into a String so that it gets printed by println() properly.

System.out.println((String)tmp.getData());

should do the trick for you.

Comment: If you pass an object to println() it will get .toString() invoked, and for String, this returns the String, the casting does not help with that.