# How to start a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, computer-science

I have been trying to figure out what the linked list is for past one hour & I learned it contains nodes and link. What is this node actually ? How do you define a linked list in java ? Though I have read different program but I want the most basic one without using any direct function. How to work and access linked list? And how you store the link and nodes?
These are few questions that I am confused about. Thank you and any part answer will be appreciated .

Comment: This can be found with tiny bit of research. Have go, then try the examples.If you have an issue then post another question.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167450/linkedlist-java-traverse-and-print

Comment: I said I have checked many programs. I just can't figure it out. I have been using only arrays. @PreetSangha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list is an ordered list where one node references the next.  Your list should keep track of the current node, which contains a reference to the next node.  When the list is iterated the current node is switched to its next node, which contains a reference to the next node.  The cycle continues from there.

A simple google search reveals much information about a LinkedList.  This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) explains it quite well.

Maybe an illustration of a node interface would help.

```
public interface Node(){

    public Node next();
    public Node prev();
}
```

Using this interface you can create a "chain" of nodes since a node has a reference to the next and previous nodes.

**I should note I may have misread your question, I thought you wanted to create your own implementation.**

Comment: Yeah I've read that. The implementation is a little confusing.

Comment: @Neer What part is confusing?

Comment: How the links actually works? How can I access it all.

Comment: Kevin Bowsersox Thanks ! Now its quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is not something you need to worry about to be able to use the list:

```
    List<String> yourList = new LinkedList<String>();

    yourList.add("item1");
    yourList.add("item2");
    // etc

    // iterating example
    for(String currentNodeElementOrWhatever : yourList) {
       // use this element somehow
       System.out.println(currentNodeElementOrWhatever);
    }
```

in this case "item1" and "item2" are nodes and they would each have a link to their next node so item1 -> item2 and item2 -> null as it is the last item.

Comment: Thanks :) Where and how to use the links. Is it implemented automatically or I need to implement the links too. And in case of integer can I use <int>?

Comment: the links are just implementation detail, i can provide more info but if you just want to get running you really dont need this right now. You can use int but you must declare the list like so: List<Integer> yourList = new LinkedList<Integer>(); this is called autoboxing which you can read more about if you like too.

Comment: To use the list you can do stuff like yourList.get(0), yourList.get(1) etc or you can use an iterator via yourList.iterator.next(), be careful here though it is generally best to iterate through the list using Java foreach loop, ill add that to the code above

Comment: Ok that will be the best thing. Yeah I was wanting something like this.

Comment: @Neer, consider looking over the collections provided in java.util these tools are not secrets.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: also, most java programs use lists, you could go to github and download some java code from a real world project and take a look how they're using them

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class example for Node.

```
public class Node<T>{
      Node next;
      T value;
}
```

Example of a pseudo code implementation for LinkedList:

```
Add( val){
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.next = firstNode;
    tailNode.next = newNode;
    newNode.value = val;
}

Get( idx){
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    while(idx--!= 0)
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    return currentNode.value;
}

Delete(idx){
   Node nodeToRemove= firstNode;
   while(idx-- > 0)
        nodeToRemove= currentNode.next;
    nodeToRemove.next = null;
}
```