# Java displaying array one by one by using indexes

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am having trouble displaying an array by index, I don't know why this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
// create token2
    String token2 = "";

    // create Scanner inFile2
    Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File
    ("/Users/timothylee/KeyWestHumid.txt")).
            useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    // create temps2
    List<String> temps2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    // while loop
    while(inFile2.hasNext()){

        // find next
        token2 = inFile2.next();

        // initialize temps2
        temps2.add(token2);
    }

    // close inFile2
    inFile2.close();

    // create array
    String[] tempsArray2 = temps2.toArray(new String[0]);

    // for-each loop
    for(String ss : tempsArray2){

        // display ss
        System.out.println(tempsArray2[0]);
    }
```

Comment: `I am having trouble displaying an array by index, I don't know why this is happening`. What's the `trouble`, what's the `display`, and what is `happening`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Your code simply makes no sense.

Comment: improve the last line: `System.out.println(ss);`

Comment: Here is an answer that may be useful in helping you traverse your linked list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167545/772020

Answer (score 1):

```
// for-each loop
for(String ss : tempsArray2){

    // display ss
    System.out.println(tempsArray2[0]);
```

your problem is here. you're not actually using the `ss` variable at all, you're simply displaying the first string each time around the loop.

Comment: @user2967353, if you're tyring to use an enhanced `for` loop, you should learn how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

improve your for loop:

```
// for-each loop
for(int i=0;i<tempsArray2.length;i++){
    // display ss
    System.out.println(tempsArray2[i]);
}
```

If you prefer `for-each`:

```
// for-each loop
for(String ss : tempsArray2){

    // display ss
    System.out.println(ss);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest the first way, since OP seems to not know how to use enhanced `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

You have put in your enhanced `for` loop correctly, its only the items you are not picking properly. Using enhanced for loop loop allows you to pick items without using indexes.

Change your loop from

```
// for-each loop
    for(String ss : tempsArray2){

        // display ss
        System.out.println(tempsArray2[0]);
    }
```

to

```
// for-each loop
    for(String ss : tempsArray2){

        // display ss
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
```