# LinkedListNode in Java

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to convert a C# code to Java. I have almost converted every thing except the three lines within `if` condition.

the C# code

```
LinkedList<T> buk = new LinkedList();
LinkedListNode<T> current = buk.First;
LinkedListNode<T> previous = null;
if (fooCondition) {
    previous = current.Previous;
} else {
    previous = current;
    current = current.Next;
}
```

The equivalent Java code

```
LinkedList<T> buk = new LinkedList<>();
T current = buckets.getFirst();
T previous = null;
if (fooCondition) {
    ?                   //previous = current.Previous;  
} else {
    ?                   //previous = current;
    ?                   //current = current.Next;
}
```

As there is no `LinkedListNode` class in the Java, can any one suggest what would be the equivalent code in Java?

**EDIT**

It seems like the full code is important to get help. Here is the C# function from the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891055.aspx)

```
  protected void MergeBuckets()
    {
        LinkedListNode<Bucket> current = buckets.First;
        LinkedListNode<Bucket> previous = null;

        int k = (int)Math.Ceiling(1 / epsilon);             // k=1/eps as integer
        int kDiv2Add2 = (int)(Math.Ceiling(0.5 * k) + 2);   // k/2 as integer
        // at this point 1/k <= eps, k >= 2, hence requires eps >= 0.5

        // number of concecutive buckets with same count causing a 
        // merge of the oldest two of those buckets
        int numberOfSameCount = 0;

        // traverse buckets from first to last, hence in order of 
        // descending timestamp and ascending count
        while (current != null)
        {
            // previous and current bucket have same count, increment counter
            if (previous != null && previous.Value.Count == current.Value.Count)
                numberOfSameCount++;
            // current is first with that count, reset counter to 1
            else
                numberOfSameCount = 1;

            // detect need for a merge
            if (numberOfSameCount == kDiv2Add2)
            {
                // merge buckets into current and remove previous
                current.Value.Timestamp = previous.Value.Timestamp;                 // take most recent timestamp
                current.Value.Count = previous.Value.Count + current.Value.Count;   // sum the counts of the buckets, 
                                                                                    // i.e. next power of two

                buckets.Remove(previous);

                // note that a merged bucket might cause a cascade of merges due to its new count,
                // hence the new current node should point to the merged bucket otherwise the 
                // cascade might go unnoticed, temporarily violating the invariant!

                previous = current.Previous;    // merged bucket's previous, since old previous is removed
                //current = current;            // trivial, merged bucket is new current

                // at this iteration, the traversal stays in place
            }
            // no merge required, continue normally
            else
            {
                previous = current;         // old current bucket or merged bucket
                current = current.Next;     // current's or merged's next

                // at this iteration, the traversal moves to the next (older) bucket
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing an if/else with 'true' as the condition?

Comment: I just simplified it, there is a variable that is checked in if condition.

Comment: simplifying is good, as long as it preserves what's necessary

Comment: @JonathanHenson Actually, it does. All that's being asked is how to do the same things -- the condition is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanHenson Yes, there is equivalent Java code. There is a way to get this functionality in Java. Maybe not in the same way (I'm thinking Iterators) but the condition and variable declarations are only there to prevent compile errors and people like you from saying that the variables were never defined.

Comment: Iterators were my first thought, but the "previous" is the problem.

Comment: @newbiedoodle not in the same way != equivalent

Comment: @newbiedoodle and my only point, was that by seeing context, I could propose something better to port to, since the only solutions I see are to rewrite the LinkedList class.

Comment: @user3212493: Rather than using `true` as a placeholder for a condition that doesn't matter to your question, use a metasyntactic variable. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). I have inserted one for you -- `fooCondition` in the place of `true`. The `true` is more confusing/distracting than a obvious placeholder, as it just Begs for the code to be refactored and the else claused deleted, even though you don't mean literally true.

Comment: You can't reference your neighbors using the LinkedList provided by Java API. You will need to create your own java Class Node and then an another class DoublyLinkedList that uses the class Node.

There are lot of examples around, here is a link:

http://techyrajeev.blogspot.com/2012/03/generic-doubly-linked-list-in-java.html

Comment: It's also important to mention that if you're doing this for performance reasons (since the MSDN magazine link you posted seems to focus on that), your java code is very likely to perform much more poorly than the C# version due to the nature of badly implemented java generics, where your instances are going to be casted to type T at runtime instead of the actual VM properly supporting the actual generic type T like a man. Not to mention the (even worse) performance hit you get from java generics not properly supporting the so called "primitive" types.

Comment: But I though java will be more efficient

Comment: @user3212493 based on what? java's generics are FUBAR, they don't support types like `int` and they aren't even properly supported at runtime by the JVM. Your `<T>` based code is going to be translated into a bunch of `(T)` stuff by the compiler. There's no way java is going to be "more efficient" than a properly designed, properly implemented, modern platform, in any way.

Answer (score 4):

can't you use the listIterator provided by the LinkedList and use its provided methods to browse the Linked list

```
ListIterator<T> listIterator = linkedListNode.listIterator(0);
if(yourCondition && listIterator.hasNext()){
    T next = listIterator.next();
}
else if (listIterator.hasPrevious()){
    T previous = listIterator.previous();
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This has the potential to be the best answer IMHO, if you apply this directly to the OP's question.

Comment: I agree, give him a vote to call attention to it. However, I'd like to point out that previous() moves the pointer backward whereas previousIndex() will just provide a reference to the previous node's position in the list.

Comment: I'd also add that you should check if these operations can be performed by using hasPrevious() and hasNext() which return booleans indicating whether these can be performed.

Comment: You should rewrite your answer to directly port the code in question. That would probably be the best possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Java class `java.util.LinkedList` has an inner class `LinkedList.Node` which is `private`. The `Node`s in a `LinkedList` cannot be acccessed directly. Instead, refer to methods like `List.indexOf(E)` and `List.add(E, int)` or a `ListIterator` in order to insert elements at specific positions.

```
final LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(object1);
if (cond) {
    list.add(object2, list.indexOf(object1));
} else {
    list.addFirst(object2);
}
```

A frequently used idiom for dealing with `LinkedList` in Java is to create the `LinkedList` but primarily operate on it using a `ListIterator`.

```
final LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
final ListIterator<T> iterator = list.listIterator();
if (!cond && list.hasNext()) {
    list.next();
}
list.add(object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a LinkedList without nodes for it. Your code doesn't make sense, unfortunately.

A LinkedList node (in this case doubly linked) consists of the next node, the previous one, and the data in the node, as well as accessor methods. It's pretty simple to implement as it's simply a data storage structure.

```
class LinkedListNode<T> {
    LinkedListNode prevNode, nextNode;
    T data;

    public LinkedListNode getNext() {
        return nextNode;
    }
    public LinkedListNode getPrev() {
        return prevNode;
    }
    public T getValue() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setNext( LinkedListNode n ) {
        nextNode = n;
    }
    public void setPrev( LinkedListNode n ) {
        prevNode = n;
    }
    public void setValue( T data ) {
        data = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will also need to implement your own linked list that uses this LinkedListNode.

Comment: Actually in Java the normal way is to create a `LinkedList` without nodes. The class `LinkedList` will take care of the nodes for itself internally.

Comment: @Christian Hujer in this case you have stated we can traverse the linked list with iterator. We can use the hasnext() method to traverse the next.Can we traverse back and forth?

Comment: @Razib Yes you can go back and forth with a `ListIterator`, that's what distinguishes a `ListIterator` from a normal `Iterator`. See [ListIterator in Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can write the own version of `LinkedListNode` class which contains the `previous` and `next` as it's property/field. For example -

```
class LinkedListNode{

 LinkedListNode previous;
 LinkedListNode next; 

}
```

Then add some getter and setter method to access the property/field. You may add another property/field to store the value of the node. This is the basic structure.This might help you.You may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167450/linkedlist-java-traverse-and-print) link also.
Thanks

Comment: How LinkedListNode could work as LinkedList.getFirst() does not return LinkedListNode object

Answer (score -2):

```
    LinkedList<T> buk=new LinkedList<T>();
    //make list
    T current=buk.getFirst();
    T previous=null;

    if (fooCondition) {
        previous = current.previous;
    } else {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
```

and the structure of T :

```
Class T{
  public T previous;
  public T next;
  //rest
}
```

Comment: This code lacks explanation, and it assumes that `T` has `getPrevious()` and `getNext()` methods - how are they related to the `LinkedList`? How are they supposed to work?